# error when trying to update the settings

Tags: elasticsearch

i try to execute this commands via a bash script but i get these errors:

```
#!/bin/bash 

curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/_close' 

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index/_settings' -d '{ 
 "analysis": { 
    "analyzer": { 
      "ar_analyzer": { 
        "tokenizer": "standard", 
        "filter" : ["standard", "lowercase", "synonym", "ar_stemmer"] 
      }, 
      "fr_analyzer": { 
        "tokenizer": "standard", 
        "filter" : ["standard", "lowercase", "synonym", "fr_stemmer"] 
      } 
    }, 
    "filter" : { 
      "ar_stemmer" : { 
          "type" : "stemmer", 
          "name" : "arabic" 
      }, 
      "fr_stemmer" : { 
          "type" : "stemmer", 
          "name" : "french" 
      }, 
      "synonym" : { 
          "type" : "synonym", 
          "synonyms_path" : "synonyms.txt" 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}' 

curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/_open'
```

**Error stacktrace :**

> {"error":"IndexPrimaryShardNotAllocatedException[[my_index] primary
>   not allocated post
>   api]","status":409}{"error":"ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[Can't
>   update non dynamic settings[[index.analysis.filter.ar_stemmer.name ,
>   index.analysis.analyzer.fr_analyzer.filter.3,
>   index.analysis.filter.synonym.type,
>   index.analysis.analyzer.ar_analyzer.filter.0,
>   index.analysis.analyzer.fr_analyzer.filter.0,
>   index.analysis.analyzer.ar_analyzer.filter.1,
>   index.analysis.analyzer.fr_analyzer.filter.2,
>   index.analysis.analyzer.fr_analyzer.filter.1,
>   index.analysis.analyzer.ar_analyzer.filter.2,
>   index.analysis.analyzer.ar_analyzer.filter.3,
>   index.analysis.filter.ar_stemmer.type,
>   index.analysis.filter.fr_stemmer.name ,
>   index.analysis.analyzer.ar_analyzer.tokenizer,
>   index.analysis.filter.fr_stemmer.type,
>   index.analysis.analyzer.fr_analyzer.tokenizer,
>   index.analysis.filter.synonym.synonyms_path]] for open
>   indices[[my_index]]]","status":400}

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Hi i am using setting like this way may be it help you:

### Close the index

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/lookupindex/_close'
```

### Update the settings

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/lookupindex/_settings' -d '{
    "index": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "custom_standard_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "customstopwords"
                    ]
                },
                "phonetic_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "phoneticstopwords"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "customstopwords": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords": [
                        "+",
                        ".",
                        " ",
                        "ca",
                        "fl",
                        "bc",
                        "b.c",
                        "b.c.e",
                        "bce",
                        "act.c.",
                        "act",
                        "style",
                        "style of",
                        "attr.",
                        "attr",
                        "manner of",
                        "manner",
                        "circle of",
                        "circle",
                        "after",
                        "near",
                        "copy",
                        "copy after",
                        "imitator",
                        "school, copy",
                        "studio",
                        "studio of",
                        "Italian school",
                        "workshop of",
                        "workshop",
                        "16th",
                        "or",
                        "17th c.",
                        "late follower",
                        "follower of",
                        "follower",
                        "attributed",
                        "near",
                        "copy after painting",
                        "by or after",
                        "fake",
                        "and school",
                        "workshop-copy",
                        "counterproof",
                        "copy after drawing",
                        "copy of",
                        "school of",
                        "called",
                        "copy IBS",
                        "German School",
                        "placed with",
                        "attribution"
                    ]
                },
                "phoneticstopwords": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords": [
                        "+",
                        ",",
                        "-",
                        ".",
                        "ca",
                        "fl",
                        "bc",
                        "b.c",
                        "b.c.e",
                        "bce",
                        "act.c.",
                        "act",
                        "style",
                        "style of",
                        "attr.",
                        "attr",
                        "manner of",
                        "manner",
                        "circle of",
                        "circle",
                        "after",
                        "near",
                        "copy",
                        "copy after",
                        "imitator",
                        "school, copy",
                        "studio",
                        "studio of",
                        "Italian school",
                        "workshop of",
                        "workshop",
                        "16th",
                        "or",
                        "17th c.",
                        "late follower",
                        "follower of",
                        "follower",
                        "attributed",
                        "near",
                        "copy after painting",
                        "by or after",
                        "fake",
                        "and school",
                        "workshop-copy",
                        "counterproof",
                        "copy after drawing",
                        "copy of",
                        "school of",
                        "called",
                        "copy IBS",
                        "German School",
                        "placed with",
                        "attribution"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

### Reopen the index once done

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/lookupindex/_open'
```

Comment: Correct, you cannot change analyzers on a live index. You need to close it and reopen it afterwards.

Comment: Just curious how people do it on production if need arises? There you cannot close the index.

Comment: @SanjeevKumarDangi the usual pain ... create new index with new settings, reindex doc, update the alias

Comment: some people do an index alias. the alias is used by the client for ingest always. so you could create a new index and hand poke it's settings. then move the alias to the new index (move is atomic).

Answer (score 12):

I had the similar exception. Is your example complete? Are you creating the index before closing it?

In my case it was the following: "create index, close it, add settings, add other settings, add mapping, open index". Waiting for about 1s after index creation fixed the exception.

Comment: Waiting 1s between the creation of my index and its closing in order to update the settings solved the problem. Thks

Comment: ES client has an API for this, something like this in C# `client.ClusterHealth(x => x.WaitForStatus(WaitForStatus.Green));`  just so that you don't need to wait an arbitrary number

Answer (score 4):

For folks using AWS Elastic-search service, closing and opening is not allowed, They need to follow re-indexing as mentioned here.

Basically create a temp index with all mappings of current original index and add/modify those mappings and settings(where analyzers sit), delete original index and create a new index with that name and copy back all mappings and settings from temp index.