# Elasticsearch can't update non dynamic settings

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, analyzer

I am trying to create a test analyzer to experiment on analysis on Elastic Search. I have an index created called "mytest" which is available and searchable, but when I try to create a custom analyzer I get below error

```
{
"error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Can't update non dynamic settings[[index.analysis.analyzer.content.type, index.analysis.analyzer.content.tokenizer]] for open indices [[mytest]]]",
"status": 400
}
```

Now I am not sure on restrictions on updating settings but I could not find anything in documentation. I can create the analyze when creating the index, but update does not work.

Using the source below to create analyzer

```
PUT mytest/_settings
{
  "analysis" : {
    "analyzer":{
      "content":{
        "type":"custom",
        "tokenizer":"whitespace"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: this may [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367877/change-settings-and-mappings-on-existing-index-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: @keety indeed it did

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can't update the settings of index when the index is in open status. You need to close the index and update the settings and open the index.

Refer : [error when trying to update the settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758335/error-when-trying-to-update-the-settings)

Comment: Is there a workaround for this. Unfortunately, AWS does not support the _close operation

Comment: @Buts possible since 7.4: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html#es_version_7_4

Comment: @Guillaume Thanks, we actually switched all out projects to GCP recently because they resolved some of the blockers for us.

Comment: Adding python example would be nice

Comment: thank you so much! closing, updating and reopening is the way to go, unless we want to specify all the settings during the index creation

Answer (score 0):

If trying to set non-dynamic settings in Elasticsearch DSL for Python, make sure to pass them to `index.settings()` instead of the dynamic `index.put_settings()`.